# Nginx configuration for multiple ReactJs applications

Tags: node.js, reactjs, nginx, react-router-v4

I have build an system that has 3 different independent reactjs applications (app1, app2, app3). Every application uses React-Router-V4 with its application name as its basename:

For each application the router is configured as:

```
return (
        <BrowserRouter basename={baseName}>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/logout" component={Logout} />
                <Route exact path="/auth" component={Logout} />
                <Route exact path="/" component={NavComponent} />
                <Route exact path="/:screen" component={NavComponent} />
                <Route exact path="/:screen/:action" component={NavComponent} />
                <Route exact path="/:screen/:action/:id" component={NavComponent} />
                <Route component={PageNotFoundError} />
            </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
```

Where `basename` is the application name (`app1`, `app2`, `app3`)

Additionally I have an `api` and `graphql` nodejs server that runs on port 3001.

All fine for development, as I run one application at a time.

I'm now having a hard time deploying to production. I want to deploy all of then in a single server using nginx on Debian 9. So, I've built my bundles and stored then in the following directory structure:

```
/var/www/apps - Root (no files)
/var/www/apps/app1 - (app1 index.html and bundle files)
/var/www/apps/app2 - (app2 index.html and bundle files)
/var/www/apps/app3 - (app3 index.html and bundle files)
```

Here is my nginx default configuration:

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;

  root /var/www/html/apps;
  index index.html index.htm;      

  location /api {
        proxy_redirect          http://localhost:3001/  /api;
        proxy_pass_header       Server;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header        X-Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_set_header        Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header        X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_connect_timeout   5;
        proxy_read_timeout      240;
        proxy_intercept_errors  on;

        proxy_pass              http://127.0.0.1:3001;
    }

    location /graphql {
        proxy_redirect          http://localhost:3001/  /graphql;
        proxy_pass_header       Server;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header        X-Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_set_header        Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header        X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_connect_timeout   5;
        proxy_read_timeout      240;
        proxy_intercept_errors  on;

        proxy_pass              http://127.0.0.1:3001;
   }


  location ~* \.(?:manifest|appcache|html?|xml|json)$ {
    expires -1;
    # access_log logs/static.log; # I don't usually include a static log
  }

  location ~* \.(?:css|js)$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    expires 1y;
    access_log off;
    add_header Cache-Control "public";
  }

  # Any route containing a file extension (e.g. /devicesfile.js)
  location ~ ^.+\..+$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
  }

  # Any route that doesn't have a file extension (e.g. /devices)
  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }
}
```

I cannot get my pages to load on production. All I get is an empty page with 404 error whenever I try:

```
http://192.168.0.100
http://192.168.0.100/
http://192.168.0.100/apps
http://192.168.0.100/apps/app1
http://192.168.0.100/apps/app2
http://192.168.0.100/apps/app3
```

How can I adjust my ngnix configuration to support such a configuration and let my applications work properly on the production server

?